# How to modify a hex string to LE-format before passing it to `xxd -r` to view its binary contents?

Tags: bash, debian, hex, xxd

The hex string `0068732f6e69622f` represents the ASCII string `/bin/sh`, when it's stored in memory in LE-format.

Is there any Linux utiltity that will take the hex string and reverse it bytes (`2f62696e2f736800`), such that `xxd -r -ps` will display `/bin/sh`?

```
$ echo -n 0068732f6e69622f | xxd -r -ps
hs/nib/
```

I've looked into `xxd -e`, but it's not possible to use it with `-r`:

`-e          little-endian dump (incompatible with -ps,-i,-r).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo 0068732f6e69622f | rev | dd conv=swab 2>/dev/null | xxd -r -p
/bin/sh
```

- `rev` reverses the input string: `0068732f6e69622f` -> `f22696e6f2378600`
- `dd conv=swab 2>/dev/null` swaps every pair of bytes and discards `dd`'s noisy output on stderr: `f2` -> `2f`, `26` -> `62`, ...

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I think `xxd` should have an option supporting this :)